# Ho do I switch to the Magento2 Fork Mage OS?

Tags: magento2

A while ago I heard there is a Community Fork of Magento2 which will include a lot more bugfixes with faster releases.

How can I start using it for my project?

Answer (score 2):

That is Mage-OS Association: https://mage-os.org/

Mage OS now has 2 repositories:

- Magento™ Mirrors (At this time, the mirror includes all packages for Magento versions 2.3.7 through 2.4.x). This is a public repository then **no composer authentication** is required.
- Magento™ Nightly Builds

You can read more info here https://mage-os.org/distribution. They have plans to launch the Mage-OS Distribution and start accepting pull requests by the end of this year. Stay tuned for more!

**To start a new project**, you can choose the repository that fits your need:

- **Magento™ Mirrors**: `composer create-project --repository-url=https://mirror.mage-os.org/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.5 mage-os`, where **mage-os** is your project directory, you can this directory as you want.
- **Magento™ Nightly Builds**: `composer create-project --stability alpha --repository-url=https://upstream-nightly.mage-os.org magento/project-community-edition mage-os`, where **mage-os** is your project directory, you can this directory as you want.

**To switch your existing Magento project** to Mage-OS, edit the `composer.json` to change `repo.magento.com`

to `mirror.mage-os.org` if you want to use **Magento™ Mirrors** repository

to `upstream-nightly.mage-os.org` if you want to use **Magento™ Nightly Builds** repository

Run `composer update` to update package.
And run the following commands to upgrade module, compile code, reindex, and deploy static content:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```